# How to split strings into new dataframe rows depending on keywords

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a row into a new row whenever an adverb is present. However, if multiple adverbs occur in a row, then I only want to split into a new row after the last adverb.

A sample of my dataframe looks like this:

```html
                   
0         but well that's alright 
1 otherwise however we'll have to  
2                       okay sure 
3                           what?
```

With adverbs = ['but', 'well', 'otherwise', 'however'], I want the resulting df to look like this:

```html
    0             but well
    1         that's alright 
    2         otherwise however  
    3         we'll have to  
    2         okay sure 
    3         what?
```

Comment: Do you want the indices that way? Or do you want to reset the index of the dataframe in your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution, maybe it can help.
You could use the [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) package.

Using this API, you can assign each word a token. A list of possible tokens is available [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-part-of-speech-tagging-using-textblob/).

The issue is that it's not perfect to tag words, and your definition of adverb might not match theirs (for instance, `but` is a `coordinating conjunction` on the API, and the `well` tag is, for some reason, a verb. But it still works for the most part:

The splitting could be done this way

```
from textblob import TextBlob

def adv_split(s):
    annotations = TextBlob(s).tags
    # Extract adverbs (CC for coordinating conjunction or RB for adverbs)
    adv_words = [ word for word,tag in annotations 
                  if tag.startswith('CC') or tag.startswith('RB') ]
    # We have at least one adverb
    if len(adv_words) >0:
        # Get the last one
        adv_pos = s.index(adv_words[-1]) + len(adv_words[-1])
        return [s[:adv_pos], s[adv_pos:]]
    else:
        return s
```

Then, you can use the `pandas` `apply()` and the new `explode()` method (**pandas>0.25**) to split your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(["but well that's alright",
                  "otherwise however we'll have to",
                  "okay sure",
                  "what?"])
data.apply(adv_split).explode()
```

You get:

```
0                     but
0     well that's alright
1       otherwise however
1           we'll have to
2               okay sure
3                   what?
```

It's not exactly right since `well`'s tag is wrong, but you have the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[0].str.split().explode().to_frame()
df[1] = df[0].str.contains('|'.join(adverbs))
df = df.groupby([df.index, 1], sort=False).agg(' '.join).reset_index(drop=True)


print(df)
                   0
0           but well
1     that's alright
2  otherwise however
3      we'll have to
4          okay sure
5              what?
```